# Dashboards in Kibana

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, kibana, devops

I want to create a dashboard in Kibana through which we can query on the logs which are created in our services. I looked into the type of visualizations present in Kibana and don't think any of them will be useful to me. I want a dashboard which supports filter on the keys which are logged and show me the corresponding logs.

So, do I need to use any other language to create a dashboard and integrate it with Kibana?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own custom frontend with self written ElasticSearch queries and something like HighCharts to chart your data.

Why do you think that Kibana is not a good fit? Kibana lets you filter the dataset that is used to render that charts.